# Query takes very long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have this Query:

```
USE [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
SELECT *
    --V.[Location Code] --as LeveranciersName    
FROM 
(SELECT 
    V.Name as LeveranciersName, V.No_,SU.[Reorder Cycle] as frequentie
    ,SU.[Location Code] as location, V.[Freight-free Limit] AS Vrachtvrije_Limiet ,   
    SUM(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)]) as Inkoopomzet
    --CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE((VLE.[Purchase (LCY)]), '(', '-'), ')','') AS MONEY)AS Inkoopomzet

FROM 
    [Verploegen POC$Vendor] V 
    JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
    JOIN 
    [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU ON V.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
    AND SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2   
    JOIN  [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
    GROUP BY V.Name, V.No_, SU.[Location Code], su.[Reorder Cycle], V.[Freight-free Limit],VLE.[Purchase (LCY)] 

    ) AS V
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(V.Inkoopomzet)
        --SUM([Purchase (LCY)]) 
        --FOR  Location Code IN ([DB], [DL], [AM], [RD], [ZM])
        --FOR [Verploegen POC$Activity]  
        FOR location in ([AM], [DB],[DL], [RD], [ZM])           
    )AS ptt
    ORDER BY LeveranciersName  
    --[Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
```

But it takes 25 seconds.

WHat advise can you give me, so that the executing time of the query makes less time

Thank you

and other question. the output of this query is this:

```
ADW Groothandel bv  3306        300.00000000000000000000    -165404.24000000000000000000    -165404.24000000000000000000    -165404.24000000000000000000    -165404.24000000000000000000    -165404.24000000000000000000
```

But I want to parse the number to:165404.24 thank you

I try to cast like this:

```
USE [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
SELECT *
    --V.[Location Code] --as LeveranciersName    
FROM 
(SELECT 
    V.Name as LeveranciersName, V.No_,SU.[Reorder Cycle] as frequentie
    ,SU.[Location Code] as location, V.[Freight-free Limit] AS Vrachtvrije_Limiet ,   
    SUM(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)]) as Inkoopomzet
    --SUM(CAST(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)] as money),1) as Inkoopomzet)
    --CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE((VLE.[Purchase (LCY)]), '(', '-'), ')','') AS MONEY)AS Inkoopomzet

FROM 
    [Verploegen POC$Vendor] V 
    JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor Ledger Entry] VLE ON VLE.[Vendor No_] = V.No_
    AND VLE.[Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
    JOIN 
    [Verploegen POC$Stockkeeping Unit] SU ON V.No_ = SU.[Vendor No_]
    AND SU.[Reordering Policy] = 2   
    JOIN  [Verploegen POC$Item] I ON I.No_ = SU.[Item No_]
    GROUP BY V.Name, V.No_, SU.[Location Code], su.[Reorder Cycle], V.[Freight-free Limit],VLE.[Purchase (LCY)] 

    ) AS V
    PIVOT
    (
        --SUM(V.Inkoopomzet)
        SUM(CAST(VLE.[Purchase (LCY)] as money),1) as Inkoopomzet)
        --SUM([Purchase (LCY)]) 
        --FOR  Location Code IN ([DB], [DL], [AM], [RD], [ZM])
        --FOR [Verploegen POC$Activity]  
        FOR location in ([AM], [DB],[DL], [RD], [ZM])           
    )AS ptt
    ORDER BY LeveranciersName  
    --[Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
```

But it gives an error

Comment: Have you ran some profiler tool to check where the bottle neck is? If you are using MSSQL you can user SQL Server Profiler (Management Studio -> Tools) That will be a starting point.

Comment: You See that I do Select *, but how to improve that? I edit the post

Comment: Something like this select convert(decimal(3,2),round(300.00000000000000000000))

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Can you post query plan for your 25 seconds execution?